# how to avoid state reload using angular

Tags: angularjs

Have created an app that uses two separate areas to display data. One on top of the other (because that seemed like a cool idea:) )

My problem is that both are controlled by states, and I can not figure out how to make it so that the underlying state is not updated when the top layer is. However, I want the underlying layer to always be there.

This is how I have set up the states

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(''); //Setting the default to the padz

        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                url: '',
                views: {
                    "musicview": {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/music',
                        controller: 'MusicController'
                    },
                    "controlview": {
                        templateUrl: 'controlview/welcome',
                        controller: 'ControllerCV'
                    }
                }

            })
            .state('about', {
                url: 'about',
                views: {
                    "musicview": {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/music',
                        controller: 'MusicController'
                    },
                    "controlview": {
                        templateUrl: 'controlview/welcome',
                        cotroller: 'ContrillerCV'
                    }
                }

            })
            .state('config', {
                url: 'config',
                views: {
                    "musicview": {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/music',
                        controller: 'MusicController'
                    },
                    "controlview": {
                        templateUrl: 'controlview/config',
                        cotroller: 'ControllerCV'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('contact', {
                url: 'contact',
                views: {
                    "musicview": {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/music',
                        controller: 'MusicController'
                    },
                    "controlview": {
                        templateUrl: 'controlview/contact',
                        cotroller: 'ControllerCV'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('forum', {
                url: 'forum',
                views: {
                    "musicview": {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/music',
                        controller: 'MusicController'
                    },
                    "controlview": {
                        templateUrl: 'controlview/forum',
                        cotroller: 'ControllerCV'
                    }
                }
            })
```

And this is the ui-views

```
<div id="musiccontainer">
    <div ui-view="musicview"></div>
</div><!-- End of container-->

<div id="controllayer">
    <% include controlview/controls/defaults.ejs %>
        <div id="controlwindow">
            <div ui-view="controlview">
            </div>
    </div>
    <% include controlview/controls/playlog.ejs %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the both views have states the will be switching smultaneously.
Maybe if you want one of them be always present you need to remove in from view list and just have a structure like this:

```
<!-- this one will be always managed by one controller : myStaticDataController-->
<div id="musiccontainer">
   <div ng-controller="myStaticDataController">
   </div>
</div>

<!-- this one will be changing accoriding to the states-->
<div id="controllayer">
    <% include controlview/controls/defaults.ejs %>
        <div id="controlwindow">
            <div ui-view="controlview">
            </div>
    </div>
    <% include controlview/controls/playlog.ejs %>
</div>
```

Comment: So far I haven't started doing that much with the back layer, but I am planning to, it is just that I want the same background page to be there most of the time displaying the same data (and avoiding reload) then at times change it depending on the states on the front.